# Kafka producer buffering

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose there is a producer which is running and I run a consumer a few minutes later. I noticed that the consumer will consume old messages that has been produced by the producer but I don't want that happens. How can I do that? Is there any config parameters in broker to be set and solve this problem?

Comment: Did you setup the configuration of the producer `auto.offset.reset` to `latest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the use case, you didn't really provide much information about the architecture. For instance - once the consumer is up, is it a long running consumer, or does it just wake up for a short while and consumes new messages arriving?

You can take any of the following approaches:

- Filter ConsumerRecord by timestamp, so you will automatically throw away messages that were produced over configurable time.
- In my team we're using ephemeral groups. That is - each time the service goes up, we generate a new group id for the consumer group, setting `auto.offset.reset` to `latest`
- Seek to timestamp - since kafka 0.10 you can seek to a certain position. Use `consumer.offsetsForTimes` to get the offset of each topic partition for the desired time, and then use `consumer.seek` to get to the given offset.
- If you use a consumer group, but never commit to kafka, then each time the a consumer is assigned to a topic partition, it will start consuming according to `auto.offset.reset` policy...

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry that I am responding you late. Regarding the architecture, we can have long running consumers and also short running consumers. I want to make sure when the consumer is up, it consumes only new messages not old ones.